# JAVAFX imageview allow user to add tag

Tags: text, javafx, tags, imageview

I am making an image gallery using javafx, i wish to have the feature which allow the user to add some tag(for human faces) to the imageview when the user is onclick at the imageview, it should grab the position of the mouse pointed and prompt a dialog for user to enter the name for the face and save it to database.

Is this achievable by using javafx?

If yes, how should i do that?

Your help is appreciated.

### Sample output of my application below:

[image]

Comment: How would you want to re-use the data that the user enters in the dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it's possible. I created this simple example for a single `Image` that adds a button to the scene which adds a circle where the image was clicked. This should demonstrate the approach.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(...);
    imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    imageView.setFitHeight(200);
    StackPane pane = new StackPane();
    StackPane.setAlignment(imageView, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    pane.getChildren().add(imageView);
    VBox box = new VBox(pane);

    pane.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
        if (evt.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            // create node(s) that uses the click data
            Button button = new Button("Show point");
            button.setOnAction(e -> {
                // do something with the data on user interaction
                box.getChildren().remove(button);
                Circle circle = new Circle(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), 5, Color.RED);
                Pane circlePane = new Pane(circle);
                StackPane.setAlignment(circlePane, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
                pane.getChildren().add(circlePane);
            });
            box.getChildren().add(button);
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(box, 200, 300);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

For your application you would:

- Create a different event handler that creates and/or initializes the UI according to your needs or shows a dialog. You also would register the listener to the `ImageView` directly (unless you need to add some elements on top of it, like I do)
- Calculate the real click position in image coordinates using `evt.getX() * imageView.getImage().getWidth() / imageView.getLayoutBounds().getWidth()`  (absolute position) or `evt.getX() / imageView.getLayoutBounds().getWidth()` (relative position); procede accordingly for y position. Do this calculation directly in the click handler, not when the user submits the entered information, since you may want the user to be able to resize the image. Also if you use the [`viewport`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#viewportProperty) property, you need to modify the calculations accordingly.
- Create a different thread that sends the information to the database, when the user submits his/her edits. Of course you also need to store some information about the image currently shown in the `ImageView` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @fabian, i using the event.getx() and manage to show the name right at the position i want! ^^